# Sign In Google will stuck on black screen when try to Add Users Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

[image]Hi so i try to add firebase auth on my app, so i followed  the documentations in here https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth from the plugin creators it self, It works well at first, but then i'm just ecounter an error or bug, its when i'm tried to add users instead of choose users that already login in my device, after add the users it will stuck forever in black sreen like the picture above, it not giving some error message it just stuck there. So is there anyone that already has same issues like me ? is there any solutions for this ? here is my code for handle the sign in

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth
        .signInWithGoogle(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/HomeScreen');
    await prefs.setString('accesToken', googleAuth.accessToken);
    await prefs.setString('email', googleUser.email);
    await prefs.setString('displayName', googleUser.displayName);
    await prefs.setString('photoUrl', googleUser.photoUrl);


    return user;
  }
```

Comment: can you add error log ?

Comment: have you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this happens because you have **not enabled the Sign-in Method in Firebase Console**.

Just enable Required Sign-in Methods and it should work fine.

[image]

Comment: im already add it on my firebase, and this bug only occured when i'm try to login with add new account google.I don't know if they already fixed it or no , its happen long time ago.  If you try it and  works , maybe they already fix it